# Django - Update multiple integer fields at once

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'd like to update multiple integer fields at once in following model.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
     field_a = models.PositiveIntegerField()
     field_b = models.PositiveIntegerField()
     field_c = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Originally, it can be done like following code with two queries.

```
foo = Foo.objects.get(id=1)
foo.field_a += 1
foo.field_b -= 1
foo.field_c += 2
foo.save()
```

I'd like make it more simpler with `update` in one query.

However, following attempts raised error.

```
# 1st attempt
Foo.objects.filter(id=1).update(
        field_a=F('field_a')+1, 
        field_b=F('field_a')-1,
        field_c=F('field_a')+2)

# 2nd attempt
Foo.objects.filter(id=1).\
        update(field_a=F('field_a')+1).\
        update(field_b=F('field_b')-1) ).\
        update(field_c=F('field_c')+2)
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Attempt #2 cannot work for sure as update does not return the queryset, but the number of changed rows. Attempt #1 should work however. Can you please add the stack trace you get with attempt #1?

Comment: Sorry for interruption. 1st attempt works well when tried again. It would be better to close this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Form the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once):

Calls to update can also use *F expressions* to update one field based on the value of another field in the model. This is especially useful for incrementing counters based upon their current value. For example, to increment the pingback count for every entry in the blog:

```
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> Entry.objects.all().update(n_pingbacks=F('n_pingbacks') + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an instance of Foo or a queryset before you can update. You should do something like this:

```
Foo.objects.get(id=1)update(field_a=F('field_a')+1).\
        update(field_b=F('field_b')-1) ).\
        update(field_c=F('field_c')+2)
```

or

```
Foo.objects.filter(id__in=[1,3,6,7]).update(field_a=F('field_a')+1).\
        update(field_b=F('field_b')-1) ).\
        update(field_c=F('field_c')+2)
```

**Reference:** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add filter option in my code and I added it now. However, above code would raise `'long' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: If that the case, maybe this question thread helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304378/django-error-model-object-has-no-attribute-update

Comment: Thanks, but I think that solution is not about serialized `update`.

Comment: As far as I acknowledged, you better have an instance first then do the update.

Answer (score 0):

If save() is passed a list of field names in keyword argument update_fields, only the fields named in that list will be updated. This may be desirable if you want to update just one or a few fields on an object. There will be a slight performance benefit from preventing all of the model fields from being updated in the database. For example:

```
product.name = 'Name changed again'

product.save(update_fields=['name'])
```

see more docs [here]:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save