# 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'first_name'

Tags: django, python-3.7

Have `AttributeError` `'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'first_name'` Get examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304378/django-error-model-object-has-no-attribute-update). I'm don't understand what is the problem

models.py

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    patronymic = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
```

views.py

```py
def edit_employee_action(request, employee_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddEmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            edited = Employee.objects.filter(pk=employee_id)
            edited.update(
                first_name = request.POST.first_name,
                second_name = request.POST.second_name,
                patronymic = request.POST.patronymic,
                birth_date = request.POST.birth_date
            )
    else:
        form = AddEmployeeForm()
    form = AddEmployeeForm()
    return render(
        request,
        'edit_employee.html',
        context={'form': form}
    )
```

The parameter `employee_id` is correct (debugged).

Comment: Your problem probably is here `first_name = request.POST.first_name`. Provide your template where your `first_name` gets populated

Comment: Django error page includes Request information and here there is no troubles https://i.imgur.com/Y64hjaY.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using incorrectly the `request.POST`. It is actually a `dictionary. Try the following.

```
def edit_employee_action(request, employee_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddEmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            edited = Employee.objects.filter(pk=employee_id)
            edited.update(
                first_name = request.POST.get('first_name'),
                second_name = request.POST.get('second_name'),
                patronymic = request.POST.get('patronymic'),
                birth_date = request.POST.get('birth_date')
            )
    else:
        form = AddEmployeeForm()
    form = AddEmployeeForm()
    return render(
        request,
        'edit_employee.html',
        context={'form': form}
    )
```

This way even if the key does not exist you'll get a `None` value instead of an exception. Also be sure that the key values are the same in your template.

Answer (score 4):

you need to get the value from `request.POST` like this:

```
request.POST['first_name']
```

(this approach will raise KeyError if first_name is not available in request.POST)

or

```
request.POST.get('first_name')
```